# C# how to force generic argument to be type

Tags: c#, generics

i have generic method. i want generic method to limit one type. problem is derived type not to be allowed - i do not want this. example codes:

```
public static T Generate<T>(T input)
    where T : Operation // ALLOWS BinaryOperation - NOT WANT THIS
{
    //...
}
```

how to do what I request?

Comment: Why use a generic if you know the one and only type it can be?

Comment: Question - Doesn't it seem odd to you that your trying to use a `generic` type to work with a `specific` type?

Comment: @AustinSalonen, asawyer: If the type is a `struct` and the constraint is an `interface`, then it won't be boxed this way. But if you just put the interface name, then it does. (Another thing: it lets you pass the type to some other generic, but you'd lose that information if you just passed the base type.)

Answer (score 10):

> problem is derived type not to be allowed

There is no way to enforce this constraint, without checking it at runtime.  Doing so would be a violation of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which states that any type *should* allow you to pass in a derived type without restriction.

If you *must* enforce this, it will only work with a runtime check, like:

```
public static T Generate<T>(T input)
    where T : Operation // ALLOWS BinaryOperation - NOT WANT THIS
{
    // Checks to see if it is "Operation" (and not derived type)
    if (input.GetType() != typeof(Operation))
    {
        // Handle bad case here...
    }

    // Alternatively, if you only want to not allow "BinaryOperation", you can do:
    if (input is BinaryOperation)
    {
        // Handle "bad" case of a BinaryOperation passed in here...
    }
}
```

Note that, in this case, there's really no reason to make it generic, as the same code would work as:

```
public static Operation Generate(Operation input)
{ // ...
```

Comment: Making it not generic will still allow the use of a BinaryOperation

Comment: I was thinking how I would answer this and I started to read your answer.  I thought, "this guys is right on!  That's exactly the way I would do it!"  Then I noticed it was @ReedCopsey... :)

Comment: @cadrell0 Yes - I wasn't trying to suggest otherwise - I was more pointing out that there's no reason to make it generic if you're always using the same type.

Comment: @Reed Please don't mistake that for a criticism of the answer.  I was just pointing out that is does not satisfy the ridiculous requirement of the OP to break both generics and inheritance.

Comment: @cadrell0 I understood what you were saying :)  No criticism or offense taken.

Comment: Thank you for calling out Liskov Substitution Principal. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to force a method to accept only one specific type like `Operation` if the type is not a struct or a sealed class.

**Let's me show this in a example why this won't work anyway:**

```
public void Generate<T>(Operation op) 
    // We assume that there is the keyword "force" to allow only Operation classes
    // to be passed
    where T : force Operation
{ ... }

public void DoSomething()
{
    Generate(new BitOperation()); // Will not build
    // "GetOperation" retrieves a Operation class, but at this point you dont
    // know if its "Operation" or not
    Operation op = GetOperation();
    Generate(op); // Will pass
}

public Operation GetOperation() { return new BitOperation(); }
```

As you can see it will be easy to pass a `BitOperation` even when there is a restriction.

### Solution

There is only one solution beside the others mentioned above ( struct, sealed ): *Runtime Check.*
You can write yourself a little helper method for this.

```
public class RuntimeHelper
{
    public static void CheckType<T>(this Object @this)
    {
        if (typeof(T) != @this.GetType())
            throw new ....;
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
public void Generate(Operation op)
{
    op.CheckType<Operation>(); // Throws an error when BitOperation is passed
}
```

#### Little Note

If you want to speed up the helper you could use a generic class `RuntimeHelper<T>` with a static readonly type variable which has the type of T.

When you're doing this you cannot longer use extension methods so the call would look like this:

```
RuntimeHelper<Operation>.CheckType(op);
```